# ¿Cómo imprimir información desde una API?

Tags: api, ios, swift, app, print

Estoy trabajando con una API en swift, mi código no trae ninguna información cuando intento imprimir la data.

Sin embargo en el curso que estoy haciendo el profesor y yo tenemos el mismo código, pero el mío no imprime la data.

Este es mi código:

```
**import Foundation

struct WeatherManager {
    let weatherURL =
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?appid=key&units=imperial"

    func fetchWeather(cityName: String) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
        print(urlString)
    }

    func performRequest(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: handle( data: response: error: ))
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func handle(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?){
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        } if let safeData = data {
            let something = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
            print(something)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay continuidad entre unas funciones y otras, y no queda claro cómo llamas a la petición.

Por ejemplo 'fetchWeather', que se supone hace la petición, no hace la petición de nada y tampoco devuelve la cadena interpolando los parámetros.

En el 'completionHandler', los parámetros del 'handle' no están separados por comas, lo que te dará error. Tampoco estás pasando valor alguno en ellos.

Te planteo una solución básica que puedes pegar como playground, y una solución más extensa desacoplando cada parte.

Tenemos una extensión que nos convierte un Fahrenheit a una cadena formateada (para pintarlo bonito):

```
extension Double {
    func fahrenheitToCelsiusString() -> String {
        let celsius = (self - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0
        let celsiusString = "\(String(format: "%.1f", celsius))ºC"
        return celsiusString
    }
}
```

En base a tu petición, también necesitamos un modelo básico para realizar la decodificación del JSON:

```
struct WeatherModel: Codable {
    let message: String
    let cod: String
    let count: Int
    let list: [LocalityList]
}

struct LocalityList: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let main: LocalityMain
}

struct LocalityMain: Codable {
    let temp, feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case feelsLike = "feels_like"
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
    }
}
```

La implementación sencilla se puede refactorizar en funciones más pequeñas. Pero para que se entienda toda la secuencia:

```
class MainView {
    
    func actionButton() {
        let inputText = "Madrid"
        getWeather(cityName: inputText)
    }
    
    private func getWeather(cityName: String) {

        let apiKey = "YourOwnApiKey"
        let weatherURL =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?appid=\(apiKey)&units=imperial"
        
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!) { data, response, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = response.statusCode
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    do {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let weather = try decoder.decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)
                        let weatherList = weather.list
                        
                        guard let firstWeather = weatherList.first else {
                            print("No data available")
                            return
                        }
                        
                        let elements = weather.count
                        let name = firstWeather.name
                        let minTemp = firstWeather.main.tempMin.fahrenheitToCelsiusString()
                        let maxTemp = firstWeather.main.tempMax.fahrenheitToCelsiusString()
                        let temp = firstWeather.main.temp.fahrenheitToCelsiusString()
                        let weatherString = "Elements \(elements) - \(name) - \(minTemp) < \(temp) < \(maxTemp)"
                        
                        print("Data: \(weatherString)")
                    } catch let error {
                        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error: Status code \(statusCode)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: Network error")
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
}
```

La solución 'mejorada' separa responsabilidades. Empezamos con la vista:

```
/*
La vista debe ser tonta, así que cuando recibe la acción de buscar
 la cadena introducida, se la pasa al presenter / viewModel
 para que le consiga datos sin importar si los trae de caché,
 de base de datos o de red porque no le importa
 */
class MainView {
    let viewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    func actionButton() {
        let inputText = "Madrid"
        getWeather(cityName: inputText)
    }
    
    private func getWeather(cityName: String) {
        viewModel.getWeather(cityName: cityName) { weatherString in
            print("Data: \(weatherString)")
        } failure: { errorString in
            print(errorString)
        }
    }
}
```

Le sigue el presenter / viewModel:

```
 /*
  El presenter o viewModel es quien adapta o presenta los datos recibidos
  del repositorio para mostrar en la vista (que debería ser tonta)
 */
class MyViewModel {
    let repository = MyRepository()
    
    func getWeather(cityName: String, success: @escaping(String) -> Void, failure: @escaping(String) -> Void) {
        repository.getWeather(cityName: cityName) { weather in
            guard let firstWeather = weather.first else {
                failure("No data available")
                return
            }
            
            let elements = weather.count
            let name = firstWeather.name
            let minTemp = firstWeather.main.tempMin.fahrenheitToCelsiusString()
            let maxTemp = firstWeather.main.tempMax.fahrenheitToCelsiusString()
            let temp = firstWeather.main.temp.fahrenheitToCelsiusString()
            let weatherString = "Elements \(elements) - \(name) - \(minTemp) < \(temp) < \(maxTemp)"
            
            success(weatherString)
        } failure: { errorString in
            failure(errorString)
        }
    }
}
```

Luego podemos armar un repositorio para preparar el endpoint:

```
/*
 Cada repositorio prepara la URL del endpoint al que apunta,
 y se encarga de decodificar (o mapear) los datos al 'viewModel'
 */
class MyRepository {
    let cm = MyConnectionManager()
    
    func getWeather(cityName: String, success: @escaping([LocalityList]) -> Void, failure: @escaping(String) -> Void) {
        let apiKey = "YourOwnApiKey"
        let weatherURL =
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?appid=\(apiKey)&units=imperial"
        
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&q=\(cityName)"
        
        cm.getData(urlString: urlString) { data in
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let weather = try decoder.decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)
                let weatherList = weather.list
                success(weatherList)
            } catch let error {
                failure("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } failure: { stringError in
            failure(stringError)
        }
    }
}
```

Y por último el administrador de conexiones, que realizará la petición de red:

```
/*
 Capa de conexión que puede centralizar todas las peticiones, 
 gestiona el código de error o respuesta de la red,
 y devuelve a cada repositorio los datos que recibe
 */
class MyConnectionManager {
    func getData(urlString: String, success: @escaping(Data) -> Void, failure: @escaping(String) -> Void) {
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!) { data, response, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                failure("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = response.statusCode
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    success(data)
                } else {
                    failure("Error: Status code \(statusCode)")
                }
            } else {
                failure("Error: Network error")
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Finalmente podemos inicializar el ejemplo con:

```
let mainView = MainView()
mainView.actionButton()
```

Y nos devolverá a la vista principal la siguiente información:

```
Data: Elements 5 - Madrid - 7.3ºC < 11.1ºC < 13.7ºC
```

O bien un error si falta el apiKey:

```
Error: Status code 401
```

Si no te vale la versión extendida, trata de simplificar la versión básica en funciones más pequeñas y utiliza los 'callbacks' (success / failure) para retornar datos entre funciones.

Un saludo.